# How can I check if an object in Typescript is a plain object or an instance of a class?

Tags: typescript

To be more precise:
I need to separate all primitive types + plain objects from all class instances.

```
let x = {y:5} // is OK

class X {
y = 5;
}
let x = new X(); // is not OK
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no foolproof way to detect plain objects versus classes. The best you might be able to do is check if its prototype matches that of a plain object. For completeness, you can also check if the prototype is `null` as that's a valid plain object when created with `Object.create(null)`

```js
function isPlainObject(obj) {
  const prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
  return  prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf({}) ||
    prototype === null;
}

class X {
  y = 5;
}

let classInstance = new X();
let plainObject = {y: 5};
let noPrototypeObject = Object.create(null);

console.log(isPlainObject(classInstance));     //false
console.log(isPlainObject(plainObject));       //true
console.log(isPlainObject(noPrototypeObject)); //true
```

This will work as long as no excessive changes are made to prototypes. If the code tampers in any way with those, you might get false negatives:

```js
function isPlainObject(obj) {
  const prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
  return  prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf({}) ||
    prototype === null;
}

let plainObject = {y: 5};
let objectCreatedWithNonDefaultPrototype = Object.create({foo: 1});
let objectWithChangedPrototype = Object.create(plainObject);
Object.setPrototypeOf(objectWithChangedPrototype, {bar: 2}) //change the prototype

console.log(isPlainObject(objectCreatedWithNonDefaultPrototype)); //false
console.log(isPlainObject(objectWithChangedPrototype));           //false
```

or false positives:

```js
function isPlainObject(obj) {
  const prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
  return  prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf({}) ||
    prototype === null;
}

class X {
  y = 5;
}

let classInstance = new X();
let classInstanceWithChangedPrototype = new X();
Object.setPrototypeOf(classInstanceWithChangedPrototype, null);

console.log(isPlainObject(classInstance));                     //false
console.log(isPlainObject(classInstanceWithChangedPrototype)); //true
```

You could alternatively check the `constructor` property from the prototype. It can work better for detecting `obj = Object.create({foo: 1})` where `obj` will be a plain object with another plain object as the prototype.

```js
function isPlainObject(obj) {
  const prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
  return  prototype === null || prototype.constructor === Object;
}

class X {
  y = 5;
}

let classInstance = new X();
let plainObject = {y: 5};
let noPrototypeObject = Object.create(null);
let objectCreatedWithNonDefaultPrototype = Object.create({foo: 1});
let objectWithChangedPrototype = Object.create(plainObject);
Object.setPrototypeOf(objectWithChangedPrototype, {bar: 2}) //change the prototype

console.log(isPlainObject(classInstance));                        //false
console.log(isPlainObject(plainObject));                          //true
console.log(isPlainObject(noPrototypeObject));                    //true
console.log(isPlainObject(objectCreatedWithNonDefaultPrototype)); //true
console.log(isPlainObject(objectWithChangedPrototype));           //true
```

This is still not bulletproof, as the constructor can still be overridden. However, that would very likely be code that's actively trying to hide itself. Most objects should be detectable with either of the two methods.

In order to find all primitives and plain objects, you can leverage `typeof` as it will report the types. Note that `typeof null` is `"object"`, so it needs an extra check:

```js
function isPlainObject(obj) {
  const prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
  return  prototype === null || prototype.constructor === Object;
}

function isPrimitive(x) {
  return x === null || (typeof x !== "function" && typeof x !== "object")
}

function filter(x) {
  return isPrimitive(x) || isPlainObject(x);
}
```