# TypeScript function to convert JSON

Tags: json, typescript

I wrote a function that takes as input a structure (of type `Struct`) that can contain primitive types as well as `Map` and `Set` objects, and converts it into something that can be JSON-serialized. Examples of input:

```
let a = 'hello'; // -> "hello"
let b = new Map<string, Set<number>>([['a', new Set<number>([1, 3])]]); // -> {"a": [1, 3]}
let c = {a: new Set<number[]>([[1, 2]])}; // -> {"a": [[1, 2]]}
let d = [{e: false}]; // -> [{"e": false}]
```

However, I find my code particularly verbose, and I am really not sure about its safety:

```
type Json = string | number | boolean | null | Json[] | { [key: string]: Json };
type Struct = Json | Struct[] | { [key: string]: Struct } | Map<string, Struct> | Set<Struct>;

function isJson(test: any): test is Json {
    if (test == null || ['string', 'number', 'boolean'].indexOf(typeof test) != -1)
        return true;
    if (Array.isArray(test)) {
        // if at least one of the values is not JSON serializable, the array is not JSON-serializable
        for (let value of test)
            if (!isJson(value))
                return false;
        return true;
    }
    if (typeof test == 'object') {
        // if it is not a plain object, the object is not JSON-serializable
        if (Object.getPrototypeOf(test) != null && test.constructor != Object)
            return false;
        // if there are symbol properties, the object is not JSON-serializable
        if (Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(test).length > 0)
            return false;
        // if at least one of the values is not JSON serializable, the object is not JSON-serializable
        for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(test))
            if (!isJson(test[key]))
                return false;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function toJson(struct: Struct) {
    let json: Json = null;
    if (isJson(struct))
        json = struct;
    else if (Array.isArray(struct) || struct instanceof Set) {
        json = [];
        let structCast = struct instanceof Set ? struct as Set<Struct> : struct as Struct[];
        for (let value of structCast)
            json.push(toJson(value));
    }
    else if (Object.getPrototypeOf(struct) == null || struct.constructor == Object || struct instanceof Map) {
        json = {};
        let structCast = struct instanceof Map ? struct as Map<string, Struct> : Object.entries(struct);
        for (let [key, value] of structCast)
            json[key] = toJson(value);
    }
    return json;
}
```

I am especially annoyed by the `isJson` function. Is there no way to get rid of it? I know that most of the typechecking is lost after compilation in TypeScript, but is there a better way do what I want?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `if (test.constructor != Object)` fails for `Object.create(null)`

Comment: @VLAZ How to check for that then?

Comment: `Object.getPrototypeOf(a) === null` see a bit more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63228981/)

Comment: Thank you. Do we still need the triple equals in TypeScript?

Comment: Sort of "no", but better be safe than sorry. Also, `let [key, value] of Object.entries(test)` will only go over regular keys, skipping any symbol keys. Thus `typeof key != 'string'` will always be `true`.

Comment: Is this question mostly about the implementation or about the typing?  You're happy with `toJson("hello")`'s return type being `Json` as opposed to `string`?

Comment: @jcalz yes because afterwards I can simply `JSON.stringify` the output. Maybe I should rename my type to `JsonSerializable` to avoid the confusion. I just wanted to know if there is a simpler scheme to check the types in the `toJson` function. For example, if simply doing `struct instanceof Json` was possible, it would make the `isJson` function redundant. @VLAZ I think you meant it will always be false.

Comment: Oh, I'm not talking about serialization.  Let me ask with a different example.  If you call `toJson(12345)`, the output at runtime will be a number, but the function `toJson()`'s output type is `Json`, which is much wider than `number`.  It is possible to give `toJson()` a generic type signature which would allow `const s = new Set([1,2,3]); const j = toJson({a: s})` to have the compiler infer `j` to be of type `{a: number[]}` instead of just `Json`. If you are happy with just `Json`, great. If not, and your question was interested in a generic signature, I could provide one.

Comment: That is kind of you, but I'm more interested in getting rid of the `isJson` function. If you write an answer, I will certainly upvote it but I don't think I will accept it. I updated my post, added a clarification on what I want and corrected the mistakes pointed out by VLAZ.

Comment: @JacopoStanchi let me see if I understood this correctly - `isJson` should check if the value can be serialised to JSON without losing any data, right? And a map can be converted to an object, so `new Map([["foo", 1], ["bar", 2]])` is OK, because it can be turned to `{foo: 1, bar: 2}`, similar thing with a set - it can be converted to an array. So those should be accepted (as long as the values are also valid). Did I understand everything correctly?

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, `isJson` checks that the struct can be casted as is as `Json`. I assume this function is needed because we cannot do `struct instanceof Json` or any other simple type check like `typeof`: the `Json` type does not exist anymore after the compilation, so no check can be done at runtime. You are correct for the `Map` and `Set`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you're writing TypeScript code and the users of `toJson()` are also writing TypeScript code.  If that's not true, and if the `toJson()` function is called by some pure JavaScript code somewhere, then you lose any compile time guarantees and will need to add as many runtime checks to `toJson()` as you feel necessary.  From here on out I assume all the relevant code will pass through a compile step.

In this case, you can probably stop worrying about some of the strange edge cases you're dealing with inside `isJson()`.  If the TypeScript `Struct` type definition already prohibits something then you don't need to write runtime code to deal with it.  On the other hand, anything that `Struct` allows but you'd like to disallow will need runtime checks.  For example, it's not generally possible in TypeScript to say "reject object types with any `symbol`-valued keys".  You can use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) to make the compiler reject any object types *known* to have such keys, but this is more complex, and does not work on the general case where an object of type like `{a: string}` may or may not have additional unknown keys.  I would suggest that, if you really need such checks, to do so by `throw` statement, since you can't catch them before runtime anyway (unless you want `toJson()` to return `Json | undefined` or some other failure marker).

---

So, let's approach this by merging the `isJson()` checks we need into the `toJson()` function and eliminating `isJson()`. Here's one possible implementation of `toJson()`:

```
function toJson(struct: Struct): Json {
  if (struct === null || typeof struct === "string" ||
    typeof struct === "number" || typeof struct === "boolean") {
    return struct;
  }
  if (Array.isArray(struct)) {
    return struct.map(toJson);
  }
  if (struct instanceof Set) {
    return Array.from(struct).map(toJson);
  }
  if (struct instanceof Map) {
    return Object.fromEntries(
      Array.from(struct).map(([k, v]) => [k, toJson(v)])
    );
  }
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(struct).map(([k, v]) => [k, toJson(v)])
  );
}
```

The four primitive checks at the beginning could be refactored to an `array.includes()` or similar code, but then the TypeScript compiler won't understand what's going on and you'd need `return struct as Json`.  The way I've got it is more verbose but the compiler is 100% sure that `struct` is a valid `Json` inside that block.  Either way is fine.

The rest of the checks are just using built in JavaScript functions and methods like [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

---

As for the typings, if you want, you can give `toJson()` a call signature that tries to actually map the input type to the output type.  For example:

```
type ToJson<T> =
  Struct extends T ? Json :
  Json extends T ? T :
  T extends Map<infer K, infer S> ? { [P in Extract<K, string>]: ToJson<S> } :
  T extends Set<infer S> ? ToJson<S>[] :
  T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: ToJson<T[K]> } :
  T;

function toJson<T extends Struct>(struct: T): ToJson<T>;
```

`ToJson<T>` is similar to the implementation, but represented as a type operation.  If the input type `T` is just `Struct`, then output `Json`.  If it's already a subtype of `Json`, then output `T`.  If it's a `Map<K, S>`, then produce an object whose keys are `K` and whose values are `ToJson<S>`.  If it's a `Set<S>`, then output an array whose elements are `ToJson<S>`.  And if it's an object (arrays are included), then map all the entries via `ToJson`.  Finally, if it's just a primitive type, return the primitive type.

---

Let's see if this all works:

```
const foo = {
  str: "hello",
  num: 123,
  boo: true,
  nul: null,
  jArr: ["one", 2, { x: 3 }],
  jObj: { a: "one", b: 2, c: { x: 3 } },
  set: new Set([1, 2, 3]),
  map: new Map([["a", 1], ["b", 2]])
}

const json = toJson(foo);
```

The type seen by the compiler is as follows:

```
/* const json: {
    str: string;
    num: number;
    boo: boolean;
    nul: null;
    jArr: (string | number | {
        x: number;
    })[];
    jObj: {
        a: string;
        b: number;
        c: {
            x: number;
        };
    };
    set: number[];
    map: {
        [x: string]: number;
    };
} */
```

Note how the `set` and `map` properties have been transformed.  Let's make sure the implementation worked also:

```
console.log(json);
/* {
  "str": "hello",
  "num": 123,
  "boo": true,
  "nul": null,
  "jArr": [
    "one",
    2,
    {
      "x": 3
    }
  ],
  "jObj": {
    "a": "one",
    "b": 2,
    "c": {
      "x": 3
    }
  },
  "set": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ],
  "map": {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
  }
} */
```

Also good. The fact that the compiler type and the implementation value agree means that you can, if you want, perform other operations on it and get some type checking and hints:

```
console.log(json.set[0].toFixed(2)); // 1.00
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAUgzgewHZQLxTsATgSyQcygB8okBXAWwCMItioqEEAbCAQxRPOefvmQDaAXXoBvKAIDWEEAC4M2PPiHz+KAL4BuAFChIUAMrYyAY2BpYiToeNnhYidLkLcBFTaynz6+gFk2YAA8mK74ADQeXgB89AYQwIFGnmZROrrg0AAqCGqBmTGo2lCRZlAQAB7AEEgAJnBQmVAA-JbIULJFrSgVVbX1jS2NHcWNPdV1UP5BeABmtFAA0hGz8wYxLeICAApQeFAAopVYbGaBSy5KUe7ZuWtQPsMNZZXj9XEJK3R3gzlWiVH2R6jF59KAIKgAKwgpQ2EgWuxQTgQMwa11+yDyAgWQhiD06mTSMzISDMODawHRSDyz16EyS0QAFCEvPJMgBKVmUvKpbREknAMkoClqJm2YDyelmDldKCiTo4FGi5LmVCq0hkHjEEh6CDIlxeNBqgBEISURq1nWKOr1zNKqvQRvI1Fo5qI2oyNrFhodjBY7CQRrZsstUCw8TIWBQtuAOmK6nlioAglhjiAAHQ4ODJ1NKrxsoNy4rFMPACNRsVpigBBnCqxs2P3BNQXOlPCYDgmXUo94FkMlstQbNsdMzLAICgt4BsyvV2vIeudePFBXN6MI9skruTAK9ouh8ORqAAeUh0OAadH4-2SEUEDgDJDxSHI7HE+j06rYAZDKkEQAbkIQaoDEv5QHOSAMn+bKASGC5xp0-aHieUJmBer7Xre94hshZ5ptUmGTh+1Y-pI-6AWgIGkWBlKQdBbKdAu8baNoJjIJgUAzEwFiFi48hGgAFhAPAIEaYSdE68gAIwAEwAMxicUvryMYEAKeqzDyNwzBqRC2byAIRrIBAolQNJETiOU8iyfcQg6ch8jiGwfFGSZVDyGZUAmA5UCWVA1k+OoalwPEmkQAA7oY8Q-pJEQebJgFqZ+oURVMP4GWwJmSbZEhGlQJnSUIMFMaxSDsRCVgWOBDKcQgC4APQAFSeWx5jlcgDkhiE8imgQDbFBJ6rOlgfUMEw8i+qwHAjdwmkaswI26Sm8hKko9BOjQdAkDxe7FL5620CN6hssIC32cGO1Fk5Fy9Y+RZuYNG0jXuXmyhde63Rde2UI9H33IdI3BeKD20CdIZJedb0CL5PXKLNQ3-doPgNXVLFsX6abMAg+AMm1SD1U1PEmtgRp8YJwmiZ0jqUCTUAyfJlO+jTKlqVTzA01pLOLVgNMCCGhlIMZanFGZIbbUWRrlDTskhkuUC2ZTELITTYtGhlzkCxTe65TTItayYyu3RLUsy4uLOAzzIYxSGutFtLxTy8URqfgbWtq7TQtQNr7mLojUDI8xJWIKwGNYzjVhpoDAgAAxCGmFIAGI4OUEA1Ay0n5poUB1XVtNplHUdAA)